# disable volume per light object

Tags: light, volumetrics

Is there a way that I can control the volume properties per lamp?

I want to create beams of light that are visible (no problem with that). But to fill in some parts I'd like to use an second light, that lit's the object without being visible in a volume.

I formerly used Maya for stage design and within Maya you can assign the amount of interaction with the volume per light.

Attached a picture to clarify my problem. In this image there is a beam that I want to be visible. On the other hand, I don't want to see the volume of the area light.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Cycles this is quite easy.

Let's say you have a scene that uses volume scatter . But want to have the red light not have any volumetric effect.

[image]

All you have to do is turn off the **Ray Visibility** for Volume Scatter for that light:

[image]

Comment: Hi Susu, I'm a Eevee usser, so missed the cycles solution. Thnx for it! If there is anyone who know ho to fix this issue in Eevee I would be really happy

Comment: @PatrickNeut hence the importance of adding clear information as part of your questions. How can anyone guess?